# No wireless after resuming from suspend?

Tags: wireless, suspend-resume, atheros

When I resume my computer from suspend it doesn't want to connect to any wireless connection. It looks like it is connecting, but after a while it asks me to retype a password for wireless connection. It connect after I restart it.

I am using Toshiba Satellite A210 and Ubuntu 10.10 (I have the same problem with 10.04 and 11.04 beta2.

```
14:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR5001 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
Subsystem: Askey Computer Corp. Device 7128
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
Memory at cfcf0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: ath5k
Kernel modules: ath5k
```

Should I file a bug?

Comment: What happens if you restart the router? I have similar problems...

Comment: It doesn't do anything. It is not problem with the router, because my brother uses ubuntu 9.10 on acer aspire (not really sure witch model) and he doesn't have any problems with reconnecting after suspend.

Comment: The question http://askubuntu.com/questions/67280/wireless-doesnt-connect-after-suspend-on-an-asus-k52f has been marked as a duplicate of this one, but it should have been the other way around. The answer there is more useful than these and includes a script.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't help fix the bug, but here's a workaround.

1. Use lsmod to find out which wireless driver you're running.
2. Reproduce the problem.
3. Kill the module (sudo rmmod [your driver]).

4 Reinsert the module (sudo modprobe [your driver]).

If wireless begins working again, you can create scripts in /etc/pm to do this each time you suspend and resume. It'll add a couple of seconds to reconnecting on resume, but that's all.

Comment: This might be done via turning wireless off and on from hardware switch / networking applet too.

Answer (score 1):

It's a common problem with some hardware combinations in linux, that some features will not properly be re-initialized after resuming from a suspended state. This goes for wireless functionality, graphics functionality and more, and can vary greatly depending on your hardware configuration.

If you can reproduce it properly, you should file a bug upstream to get it fixed - it is likely that this is a bug in the drivers causing your hardware to not be reinitialized properly when resuming from sleep.

Please don't take this as a confirmation that this *is* a bug, as there are more variables in play here, but filing a bug report can help you get it resolved either very soon or in a future release.

Answer (score 0):

Though I'm sure our situation is not exactly the same, but I faced similar issue with my netbook, and the sound (& brutal) workaround was to upgrade to Ubuntu 11.10. See detail [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1919754). HTH.