# HP mini 5102 Ethernet does not work after suspend on Lubuntu 12.10

Tags: networking, ethernet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No wireless after resuming from suspend?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35592/no-wireless-after-resuming-from-suspend)

Ethernet works fine after system is rebooted

The onboard card is seen in 'lspci' as:

```
43:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. Yukon Optima 88E8059 [PCIe Gigabit Ethernet Controller with AVB] (rev 11)
```

After system being suspended the sky2 driver loads but does not enable the NIC. I have noticed that it happens when PC is left suspended for longer period of time (few houres)

Trying to reproduce it I have tried to load the sky2 driver with `modprobe sky2`. Unfortunately typing `ifconfig -a` for the onboard ethernet adapter does not list the driver once the sky2 driver is loaded.

I have searched internet and I found some information about a bug in kernel. Hovewer it was reported in 2010 so I hope it has been fixed. Here it is

http://lists.opensuse.org/opensuse-bugs/2010-02/msg01473.html

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/35592/no-wireless-after-resuming-from-suspend  and http://askubuntu.com/questions/67280/wireless-doesnt-connect-after-suspend-on-an-asus-k52f

Answer (score 0):

reloading the driver by using below desn't work.

sudo rmmod sky2

sudo modprobe sky2

I have been playing with it around and noticed that when i plug the network cable in and suspend the system without taking the cable out, after switching the system back on ethernet adapter remains fine and connection is fine. But if I then plug the cable out and suspend the system again it freezes and only reboot is left. There is an information on the screen "panic occured - switching back to text console" but i cannot do anything.

It really looks like there is a bug in the kernel but I don't know what to do with it? How can i reported and to who?

Comment: I have found some patches for that driver but i don't think they will work as they are for kernel 2.6.31. Can someone tell me do those patches are already added into my kernel and my issue is not related to it?

Comment: This post is confusing, this area is for posting answers, please add this information to your question by editing it!